# C#: Forms and if statements

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a newbie question that's been bugging me. I've been messing around with forms in visual studio. In the simple program I'm making, I want to disable/enable a button depending on whether a checkbox is ticked.

Can someone tell me why this code doesn't work? Specifically the if statement.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Do_Check();
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Do_Check();

    }

    private void Do_Check()
    {
        // button1.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked;

        if (checkBox1.Checked)
            button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Blah blah");
    }


}
```

I've commented out one way of achieving the desired result. I'm just not sure why the if statement doesn't also work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The IF statement only checks if the checkbox is checked, nothing to say what happens if the checkbox is not checked, you need to add an `else` statement

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"?

Comment: @JayV Thank you. That was such a simple oversight. It worked.

Comment: @JamesMacDonald Its a simple oversight that I have seen a few experienced programmers make now and then. You should post your own answer and accept that

Comment: Just use the code you have commented out, that is the correct code, and drop the if statement

Answer (score 3):

Your button is only enabled if the `checkBox1` is checked - but never disabled. Hence you should do something like this:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
    button1.Enabled = true;
else
    button.Enabled = false;
```

However, your commented solution with

```
button1.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked;
```

is way more elegant.